# Orbeon Forms Basic Authentication

Tags: forms, basic-authentication, orbeon

I need help setting up a basic authentication in **orbeon forms** to secure my localhost `url`, anytime I access this `path /fr/orbeon/builder/*` using basic authentication I always get `HTTP Status 403 – Forbidden`, description. The server understood the request but refuses to authorize it. What's the way out for me. I'm loosing sleep.

All I wanted to do is to redirect any user accessing the `localhos:8080/orbeon` to the login page where user can authenticate to login before they can create forms or access admin areas. I need a walk through as I have tried everything in basic authentications but I always get `error HTTP Status 403 – Forbidden`
Type Status Report

Message Access to the requested resource has been denied

Description The server understood the request but refuses to authorize it. accessing this `path : /fr/orbeon/builder/*`. Please anyone experienced with basic authentication should help me out.

Comment: _Basic Authentication_ doesn't use Login Pages...

Comment: Can you elaborate for me please,how does it work in Orbeon??????Please help me.

Comment: What Dai above says is that Servlet containers support two types of authentication at least: using HTTP BASIC auth, or using form-based auth. BASIC means the browser directly handles the auth. It's not used very often anymore. Form-based means the container shows a special page with username/password login. You say you use "basic authentication" above. Can you clarify if you mean truly HTTP BASIC? This is a setting in web.xml.

Comment: Thank you so much for your explanation as i have been mixing things up.Now i rephrase my question to how to use form-base auth. i want to require users to form login page anytime they want to access the url,to prompt login page to open and provide users and password before you can be allowed to access the url.

Comment: First, did you read the doc and do the setups in the doc? https://doc.orbeon.com/form-runner/access-control

Comment: Yes i did, my issue is how to make login page appear anytime you hit the localhost 8080 /orbeon. prompt user login page to appear before you access the area.

Answer (score 0):

In your web.xml, instead of the default:

```
<security-constraint>
    <web-resource-collection>
        <web-resource-name>Form Runner</web-resource-name>
        <url-pattern>/fr/auth</url-pattern>
    </web-resource-collection>
    <auth-constraint>
        <role-name>orbeon-user</role-name>
    </auth-constraint>
</security-constraint>
```

Try:

```
<security-constraint>
    <web-resource-collection>
        <web-resource-name>Form Runner</web-resource-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </web-resource-collection>
    <auth-constraint>
        <role-name>orbeon-user</role-name>
    </auth-constraint>
</security-constraint>
```

This will apply the constraint of a logged in user to all pages in the app.

Comment: Hi ebruchez, when i applied the /* in the url-patter of the form runner, the page came out blank. i could not open any page, what next??

Comment: Well, i've finally got it solved. Using <url-pattern>/fr/*</url-pattern> performed the magic for me.Thanks for reaching out.